# Why do PHP magical methods have to be public?

Tags: php, getter-setter, phpdoc, public-method

I use magical methods in my PHP classes but when i try to put them private, I'm warned :

> WARN: The magic method __get() must have public visibility and cannot
>   be static in ...

I wouldn't like to have these methods in Eclipse auto completion. (maybe a way with phpdoc ?)
So my question is, why must these methods be public ?

Comment: Only [overloading magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) must be public. This requirement is not enforced on stuff like constructors and destructors.

Comment: These methods will be called from outside the class context, so what's surprising about their need to be public?

Comment: @KerrekSB : call inaccessible attribute from outside class context mean call __get method from outside ? so it would be the answer !

Comment: What php version is this? I don't get any such warning.

Comment: @ExplosionPills enable error reporting

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you are invoking the methods from a scope outside of the class.

For example:

```
// this can be any class with __get() and __set methods
$YourClass = new YourOverloadableClass();

// this is an overloaded property
$YourClass->overloaded = 'test';
```

The above code is "converted" to:

```
$YourClass->__set('overloaded', 'test');
```

Later when you get the property value like:

```
$var = $YourClass->overloaded;
```

This code is "converted" to:

```
$YourClass->__get('overloaded');
```

In each case the magic method, `__get` and `__set`, are being invoked from outside the class so those methods will need to be `public`.

Comment: I don't think "public scope" is a word... at least it obscures what's really going on :-(

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I think a more appropriate term would be "calling scope".

Comment: You're right, public scope isn't really descriptive of what's going on.  Will modify the answer to be clearer on what is happening.